# AngularJS $route.current is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I try to put `action` parameter in the `$routeProvider`. The problem is, I get `$route.current is undefined` error. Why ?

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/abc', {
                      ...
                      action: 'X'
                  })
}]);

myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$location', 'authService',
    function ($rootScope, $location, $route, authService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (currentRoute, previousRoute) {
            if ($route.current.action) {
                $rootScope.action = $route.current.action;
            }
        });
   )]
```

Comment: You have `currentRoute` as a parameter, any reason you're not using it? (btw you probably need to change that signature to `function (ev, currentRoute, previousRoute)`)

Answer (score -2):

I think the function paramerters have an incorrect order, following is the correct order.

```
function ($rootScope, $route, $location, authService) {
```

Also, as stated by @Clive, you probably need to change the signature of the function.